# What is this aircraft parked in Oceanside Municipal Airport?

Tags: aircraft-identification, single-engine

I was on my way to the beach at Oceanside on October 2020. On 4:32, I saw multiple Cessna or Beechcraft aircraft, as well as a Velocity V-Twin, on the runway of the Oceanside Municipal Airport.

When I was looking at the further spots, I noticed an odd-looking, single-engined twin tail aircraft parked on the runway. As seen in this photo, the red arrow indicates the strange aircraft.

[image]

Comment: That’s an Ercoupe.  No longer manufactured but still many examples flying today.

Comment: It appears this one was identifiable based on the pic alone, but thanks for providing all the additional time & location info. Usually, that's necessary, and most have to be prompted to provide it.

Comment: "the red arrow indicates the strange aircraft"  Hmm, I was really wondering what that red arrow meant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely an [ERCO Ercoupe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERCO_Ercoupe). BTW, this tail configuration is called H-tail.

Note the similar-looking [Max Holste MH.52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Holste_MH.52), but with the noticeably smaller dihedral angle.

Comment: The Forney F-1 variant on wiki is exactly the same, even the color!

Comment: @bentoy13, That's because Forney bought the manufacturing rights & tooling from ERCO's successor and manufactured Ercoupes for a while under the Forney name.

Answer (score 2):

That's almost certainly an ERCO Ercoupe! It's a beautiful plane, and it actually has a fairly unique characteristic that makes it quite safe- it's characteristically IMPOSSIBLE to spin! IIRC the ailerons and rudder are both controlled by the yoke- the aircraft is always coordinated! It's a cool plane even when you don't consider that feature, but with that system in place, I think it's one of the neatest GA planes out there!